# Firebase dependencies set up correctly but still cannot resolve

Tags: android, firebase

New to firebase but when I try to use `private FirebaseAuth mAuth;` as stated in their Email Auth guide it is not able to resolve. I have set up firebase in the project and it says I have done it correctly.

Do I need to import something on that java file?

[image]

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Post the dependencies block of the module build.gradle file.

Comment: show dependencies

Comment: added to the post, thanks! @qbix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
```

Android Studio will help you with unresolved references like this one.  Click on the unresolved symbol and enter **Alt+Enter**.  The  needed import will be automatically added.

Comment: Unresolved reference: FirebaseAuth - if someone has this error, please make : Invalidate and restart in Android Studio